# How do I retrieve the data from a hbase table by doing a inner join and bringing it into hive

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I have two Hbase tables '`hbaseTable`', '`hbaseTable1`' and Hive table '`hiveTable`'
my query looks like:

```
'insert overwrite hiveTable select col1, h2.col2, col3 from hbaseTable h1,hbaseTable2 h2 where h1.col=h2.col2';
```

I need to do a inner join in hbase and bring the data to hive. We are using hive with java which gives a very poor performance. 
So planning to change the approach by using spark. i.e, spark with java
How do I connect to hbase from my JAVA code using SPARK.

now my spark code should do a join in hbase and bring in data to hive by the above query.

Please provide sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spark to load hbase data then why load it in hive?
You can use spark sql which is similar to hive and thus sql.
You can query the data without using hive at all.
For example :

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import scala.Tuple2;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SparkHbaseHive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "test");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark-Hbase").setMaster("local[3]"));
        JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> source = jsc
                .newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, TableInputFormat.class,
                        ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);
        JavaRDD<Table1Bean> rowJavaRDD = 

source.map((Function<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result>, Table1Bean>) object -> {
            Table1Bean table1Bean = new Table1Bean();
            table1Bean.setRowKey(Bytes.toString(object._1().get()));


table1Bean.setColumn1(Bytes.toString(object._2().getValue(Bytes.toBytes("colfam1"), Bytes.toBytes("col1"))));
            return table1Bean;
    });
        DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowJavaRDD, Table1Bean.class);

        //similarly create df2
        //use df.join() and then register as joinedtable or register two tables and join
        //execute sql queries

        //Example of sql query on df
        df.registerTempTable("table1");
        Arrays.stream(sqlContext.sql("select * from table1").collect()).forEach(row -> System.out.println(row.getString(0) + "," + row.getString(1)));

    }
}
public class Table1Bean {
    private String rowKey;
    private String column1;


    public String getRowKey() {
        return rowKey;
    }

    public void setRowKey(String rowKey) {
        this.rowKey = rowKey;
    }

    public String getColumn1() {
        return column1;
    }

    public void setColumn1(String column1) {
        this.column1 = column1;
    }
}
```

If you need to use hive for some reasons use HiveContext to read from hive and persist data using saveAsTable.
Let me know in case of doubts.